# How to combine date and time into timestamp?

Tags: datetime, amazon-redshift

I have the column d_date having values like "*2017-04-01 00:00:00*"
and column t_time having values like "*1970-01-01 09:43:35*" and I want to combine it to one time stamp like "*2017-04-01 09:43:35*".

Both of the input columns are of type **timestamp**.

Please help.

Comment: (d_date + t_time) is giving me this:   "2017-04-01 00:00:001970-01-01 09:43:35"

Comment: Use the date/time functions DATEADD/DATEDIFF instead of +/-: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/Date_functions_header.html

Comment: What do you mean by `I want to combine it to one time stamp`? What's the logic/intent behind this? What exactly the end result should convey?

Answer (score 1):

What about using the `TIMESTAMP(date, time)` built in function?

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP(entry_date, entry_time) AS timestamp
...
```

Comment: Rockin4Life33 - I don't see a TIMESTAMP function (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/Date_functions_header.html).  I see a TO_TIMESTAMP function, but that doesn't take the parameters you suggest.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @mherzog.  I'll update the answer when I get back to my computer.  From a quick look, it does appear something like `TO_TIMESTAMP( ( TRUNC( entry_date ) + TO_TIMESTAMP( entry_time, 'HH:MI:SS' ) ), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS' [, is_strict] )` is probably the way to go now.  I'd imagine that `TIMESTAMP` has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about redshift but [based on the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/Date_functions_header.html) I would try something like this:

```
SELECT
  DATEADD(second, 
          DATEDIFF(seconds, d_time, DATE_TRUNC('day', d_time)), 
          t_date) as dt_datetime
...
```

I'm not going to setup a redshift database just to test the suggestion above but I'm willing to help you over chat if the above does not work.

Comment: Thanks. Following worked for me:

(date(d_date) || ' ' || RIGHT(t_time,8))::TIMESTAMP

Comment: I checked your solution. It is weird that it is adding my timezone to it.

Comment: You may have to sprinkle a few `AT TIME ZONE 'XXX'` here and there in order to get this right. Date/time is more complex than it looks like - for example, in my country we have a "Day Light Savings" period - many libraries will get it wrong at DLS boundaries.